# After the mouse has changed the div custom value to the background?

Tags: jquery, html, background

I hope that jquery can get the value of DIV change_picture="http://web.com/1.png" when the div class is article-image, and then become the css background. When the mouse is removed, continue. Show the original background http://web.com/2.png.

How to write jquery, ask for guidance. thank you very much

```html
<div class="article-image cover-image homelazy" change_picture="http://web.com/1.png" style="background-image: url(http://web.com/2.png);">
</div>
```

Comment: Any code tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var originalImg = '';
  $('.cover-image').hover(function() {
    originalImg = $(this).css('background-image');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr('change_picture') + ')');
  }, function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', originalImg);
  })
})
```

```css
.cover-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="article-image cover-image homelazy" change_picture="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/y8/r/dF5SId3UHWd.svg" style="background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png);">
</div>
```

Bind the hover event to the div with the class attribute `cover-image`. When the mouse is moved in, save the original background image first, then use the `.css` method to set the new background image. When the mouse is removed, set the original background image back.